# Não consigo abrir projeto em Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tenho um projeto em *Laravel* que depois que formatei o computador não consigo mais abrí-lo. Foram realizados os seguintes passos:

1. Instalação do *XAMPP* e alteração do caminho padrão para a pasta do projeto.
2. Instalação do *Composer* e posteriormente atualização do mesmo.
3. Criação do database do projeto no *MySQL*.
4. Ao rodar o comando *PHP* `artisan migrate` e `artisan serve` aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: Migrate e Serve]

5. Na página web aparece assim:
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
6. O arquivo .env está configurado dessa forma. Essa chave estava aí desse mesmo jeito antes da máquina ter sido formatada. Ao rodar o comando php artisan key:generate dá erro e não consigo gerar a nova chave.

Code

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_NAME=SGP
APP_KEY=base64:eEtD6lSEsQGE/aDDVHgVHXKLpmaj1XzhMTtiFhOukqQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://sgp.patrimonio
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sgpmehos_bd
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

A migration que está apresentando erro é a 2017_10_22_134724_create_permissions_table.php e os códigos nela inseridos são:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePermissionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nome', 50);
            $table->string('label', 200);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('permission_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('permissions');
        Schema::dropIfExists('permission_role');
    }
}
```

Model: Permission.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Acesso;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Permission extends Model
{
    public function scopeSearch($query, $pesquisa){
        return $query->where('nome', 'like','%' .$pesquisa. '%' );
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Acesso\Role::class);
    }
}
```

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: o .env ta configurado corretamente? se sim tenta rodar esse comando php artisan migrate:refresh

Comment: editei a perguntar para deixar melhor explicado. Quanto ao comando refresh não deu certo. Fala que a base de dados não existe.

Comment: vc criou o banco sgpmehos_bd  no mysql?

Comment: Sim, criei a base de dados com esse nome.

Comment: criou um outro usuário do mysql? se for um mysql atualizado certamente o usuário root não consegue acessar o banco pelo menos eu tive esse problema aqui

Comment: Faz o seguinte então, vai la no banco de dados mysql verificar se existe alguma tabela no banco sgpmehos_db e deleta todas, depois tenta de novo!

Comment: @Bulfaitelo criei e mesmo assim continua com o mesmo erro.

Comment: @Lodi não existe tabela no banco. :(

Comment: O erro está que não existe o tabela db.permissions

Comment: Eita, vamos analisar vc tem uma migration com esse nome correto?

Comment: Roda esse comando aqui `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` é me fala o resultado dele.

Comment: Oi @Lodi, tenho sim.

Comment: @Bulfaitelo rodei o comando e deu o mesmo erro, amigo.

Comment: @Lodi vou postar a estrutura dessa migration na pergunta.

Comment: coloca o da model também, deve existir uma model, permissions, procura por protected $table = "permissions"; se não tiver adiciona essa linha e testa novamente.

Comment: Coloquei o código da model Permission.

Comment: @LucasAugustoCoelhoLopes é o seguinte na migration ter a model não vai interferir no processo pelo que eu entendi, o seu problema é ao executar o php artisan migrate, conforme muito bem mencionado aqui, verifique cuidadosamente os seguintes itens: 1. Banco de dados sgpmehos_bd foi criado? 2. Seu .env está configurado corretamente? 3. Tente executar o comando php artisan migrate:fresh, faça isso somente se estiver em homologação, não execute este comando em produção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo pelo que você informou:

Delete o banco de dados;

Reinicie o XAMP;

Crie na mão o banco de dados novamente (Verifique se o nome foi digitado corretamente);

Depois disso execute o comando "php artisan dump-autoload"

Depois: php artisan migrate --force